# Find the error in the given statement

Tags: grammaticality

(a)He will/(b)bake a cake/(c)today in the evening/(d)No error.

What option would have been correct in case this is how the question would have looked like?

I feel that it should be - **in the evening today** instead of today in the evening. But this is just my gut feeling and not based on any rule.
Can anyone guide If I am right or wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a test question fro someone learnign the English language.    Have you considered posting this on the English Language Learners site instead?

Comment: I was not aware of any such site that's why I posted this question here.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's nothing wrong in that sentence grammatically, though your gut feeling is correctly telling you that the wording isn't too great. Personally, I'd prefer the following wording instead:

> He will bake a cake this evening.

Also, your wording is no more correct/wrong than the original, so the following is also acceptable:

> He will bake a cake in the evening today.

Comment: Although temporal adverbials usually don't need any commas, putting two of them together does deserve them: "He will bake a cake today, in the evening."